# Estilos segun el sistema operativo

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

```css
.display{display: block}
```

```html
<div class="display-mobile">
    <div>
        <a href="#">Boton desktop 1</a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a href="#">Boton desktop 2</a>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="display-mobile">
    <div>
        <a href="#">Boton mobile 1</a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a href="#">Boton mobile 2</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Basandome en el siguiente codigo me gustaria saber como puediera hacer que en Windows, MacOs y Linux se mostrara unicamente mi div con la clase display-desktop, y en iOS y android se muestre unicamente mi div con la clase display-mobile

Comment: Bienvenida a [es.so] te invito a leer [ask] y de paso hacer el [tour]. Respondiendo a tu pregunta, la única forma de detectar el sistema operativo es con javascript, sin embargo tu no necesitas eso, si no algo llamado Responsive Design que se hace con CSS, investiga sobre.

Comment: No depende del OS sino del navegador. Por favor, especifica qué es lo que ves diferente o qué problema tienes con los estilos actuales. Hay _algunos_ objetos que cambian de uno a otro (los comboboxes) peeero en general, el OS no es el culpable

Answer (score 3):

Si lo que quieres es mostrar esos div dependiendo del sistema operativo, tienes al alcance una funcionalidad propia del navegador llamada [navigator.appVersion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorID/appVersion). Esto te mostrará información del tipo de navegador que el usuario está usando y por supuesto, el sistema operativo. Entonces, si haces algo como esto:

```js
let OSName="Android";

if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Win") !=-1 ) OSName="Windows";
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Mac") !=-1 ) OSName="MacOS";
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("X11") !=-1 ) OSName="UNIX";
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Linux") !=-1 ) OSName="Linux";

switch(OSName) {
  case "Windows":
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    $('#point').html(`
      <div style="height: 50px; width: 50px; background-color: #F2F110;"></div>
    `);
    break;
  case "Linux":
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
    $('#point').html(`
      <div style="height: 50px; width: 50px; background-color: #FFF100;"></div>
    `);
    break;
  case "MacOs":
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
    $('#point').html(`
      <div style="height: 50px; width: 50px; background-color: #FFF110;"></div>
    `);
    break;
  case "UNIX":
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#234567";
    $('#point').html(`
      <div style="height: 50px; width: 50px; background-color: #FFF001;"></div>
    `);
    break;
  default:
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#008910";
    $('#point').html(`
      <div style="height: 50px; width: 50px; background-color: #FFF101;"></div>
    `);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="point" style="height: 200px; width: 200px; background-color: #000;"></div>
```

Facilmente lo puedes aplicar para que muestre los divs que quieras.

Answer (score 1):

Solución por navegador:

Esto no se puede hacer con CSS, tienes que utilizar Javascript para recuperar la información del navegador con `window.navigator` y más específico, `window.navigator.userAgent`.

Como ejemplo, podrías hacer algo como esto:

```javascript
const browser = window.navigator.userAgent;
const isSafari = browser.indexOf('Safari') > 0 ? true : false;
if(isSafari){
  // hacer algo en safari suponiendo que tienes una clase
  // .d-none{display: none;}
  document.querySelectorAll('.display-mobile').forEach(el => {
    el.classList.add('d-none');
  })
}
```

---

Solución por device-size Media Query:

Lo puedes configurar con media query:

```css
/* lógica mobile-first */
.display-mobile{display: block;}
.display-desktop{display: none;}

@media screen and (min-width: 640px){
  .display-mobile{display: none;}
  .display-desktop{display: block;}
}
```

Si deseas saber más:
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: Hola muchas gracias! pero me gustaria no usar media querys ya que no me gustaria depender mucho de la resolucion si no del sistema operativo

Comment: Entiendo, edito respuesta

Answer (score 1):

Lo resolví de la siguiente manera

```
<html>
 <body>
<div id="display-desktop">
    <div>
        <a href="#">Boton desktop 1</a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a href="#">Boton desktop 2</a>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="display-mobile">
    <div>
        <a href="#">Boton mobile 1</a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a href="#">Boton mobile 2</a>
    </div>
</div>
 </body>   
</html>



<script>
    function retornarSO(){
      if(/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|OperaMini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
        document.getElementById("display-desktop").style.display = "none";
      }else{
        document.getElementById("display-mobile").style.display = "none";
      }
    }
    retornarSO();

</script>
```